# _pthread_kill +32 iOS app crashes on device not on emulator

Tags: ios, iphone

I have updated an old app, and it took a lot more work than anticipated and it is finally done... kinda. It runs fine in the emulator on the computer but when I try it on an actual device (iPhone 5) it crashes(pauses?). The first view loads fine, pressing any of the five buttons to go to the next view crashes the app. Maybe I shouldn't say "crash" it loads indefinitely.

It is the _pthread_kill + 32 that is highlighted and it says "Thread 1:signal SIGABR"

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x389091f4:  mov    r12, #328
0x389091f8:  svc    #128
0x389091fc:  blo    0x38909214                ; __pthread_kill + 32
0x38909200:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]             ; __pthread_kill + 24
0x38909204:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x38909208:  b      0x38909210                ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x3890920c:  .long  0x01e23e14                ; unknown opcode
0x38909210:  bx     r12
0x38909214:  bx     lr
```

Comment: I get the same thing in an app, hope someone wades in with an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

What it ended up being for me was a problem with Google analytics. I had an old version and it wasn't compatible with the phone or the OS. I commented out all the google analytics stuff and removed the plug in and it worked fine.